# The definite article used to speak about things in general

Tags: articles, definite-article

> Crime is a serious problem nowadays.

The definite article is not used in this sentence with the "crime" since the word means "activities breaking the law" in general, it's uncountable in the sentence given above.

But are the following sentences correct? Can the word "apple" be used with the zero article? I suppose that it can't as "apple" is a countable noun, and the definite article before the "apple" is necessary when speaking about any particular kind of fruit.

> Apple is the most common fruit in the region.
>   Apple is my favourite fruit.
>
> (Should be "the apple" in both sentences.)

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This only works for mass and abstract nouns, to my knowledge. ("Apple is my favourite **flavour**" would work, but "Apple**s are** my favourite fruit.") Someone will probably come along and correct my correction, though.

Comment: You could just say "**The** apple is the most common fruit in the region", in formal speech.

Comment: Yes, I know, but is the sentence "Apple is the most common fruit..."  incorrect?

Comment: @Yulia Yes, it is incorrect. Either Luke's "Apples" or Bluefire's "The apple" would be acceptable abstractions to use, but you would need to use one of them to make the sentence work.

Answer (score 1):

The "zero article", otherwise known as simply not using an article, either indicates a proper name, or an *abstract concept*.

> Apple is the most common fruit in the region.

This cannot be correct, because you are not talking about the abstract concept of an apple, but rather about a very real and concrete object.

> Apple is the platonic ideal of fruit.

This example is *closer* to correct, because we are now talking about the concept of the apple, but even here, apple is simple to real and concrete to be usable with the zero article.  This is also wrong.

> Apple is on my mind.

Finally, we have come to a correct sentence, thoroughly converting a concrete noun into an abstract concept that I am merely thinking about.  But even here, alone, without context, the idea of treating the word "apple" as an abstract concept is so strange that most people would reinterpret the sentence to treat "Apple" as a proper noun instead, especially since there exists a very real and well known company with the proper name of "Apple".  But it does work, grammatically, the other way... it's just a very strange idea.  You might find it in a philosophy textbook.

Comment: Upvoted, although I guess I'd say if I saw any of the three sentences printed in a book, I don't think I'd consider it calamitously wrong. I suspect I wouldn't even notice it.

Comment: I disagree completely with "apple" as an uncountable noun, unless it refers to a flavor.

Answer (score -1):

**Crime** is very serious today. Uncountable

BUT, everyday speech

**Apples** are the most common fruit in the region.   [countable]
**Apples** are my favorite fruit. [countable]

BUT, "literarily" or **as a category**:

- **The apple** has a special meaning in the history of Western painting.
- The medicinal benefits of **the apple** are much touted.

The use of **the** like that is not usually found in everyday, spoken English except maybe in a professor's lecture or a conversations among intellectuals.

- The apples on the table are mine, not yours. [specific]

Comment: Tsk, tsk, tsk. Some people just do not know the rules. Everything in my answer is exactly what the grammar books say.